# Connecting qml-signals to Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to use a qml-grid view in my code. I'm trying to couple it with my C++ code.
I've dynamically created a list view model and passed across the qml file. It works fine.
However, I'm facing trouble when I want to connect a Qml signal to Qt/c++ code. I've handled mouseArea in my Qml-rectangle and emitting a signal from there.

I'm trying to connect to the signal as follows:

```
QDeclarativeView *pQMLContainer = NULL;
TempWidget *pTemp = new TempWidget();
pQMLContainer = new QDeclarativeView(pTemp);
pQMLContainer->setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView::SizeRootObjectToView);
pQMLContainer->rootContext()->setContextProperty("imgModel", createModel() );
pQMLContainer->setSource(QUrl("../Temp/qml/gridview-example.qml"));
QObject *rootObject = dynamic_cast<QObject*>pQMLContainer->rootObject();
QObject::connect(rootObject, SIGNAL(keyPressed()), pTemp, SLOT(onKeyPressed()));
```

When the connect statement runs, I get an error: cannot connect to "null" object.
On debugging, I found I could never get "rootObject" as a valid pointer.
Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: There's no need for `dynamic_cast` - the root `QGraphicsObject` is a `QObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally get this working. I'm not sure if this is the real solution to the problem, but finally this got it working:
I was setting the qml path as a relative path to my working folder. And yes the path was indeed correct, as I could see the qml and its contents. I just happened to change the qml path from relative to the working folder to relative to "qrc" as:

```
pQMLContainer->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/gridview-example.qml"));
instead of:
pQMLContainer->setSource(QUrl("../Temp/qml/gridview-example.qml"));
```

and it started working. I'm not sure if I had to add the qml to the qrc (I've just started using qml).

Thanks everyone for your support!
Mots

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this ? (it is example code from [Qt Docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtbinding.html))

```
QObject *item = pQMLContainer->rootObject();
QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(keyPressed()),
                  pTemp, SLOT(onKeyPressed()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is pretty much straight:

in .cpp file:

```
ui->declarativeView->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/Resources/main.qml"));
QGraphicsObject *obj = ui->declarativeView->rootObject();
connect ( obj, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(itemClicked()));
```

and QML File:

```
import Qt 4.7

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    id: rect

    signal clicked

    Text {
        text: "Hello World"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            rect.clicked();
        }
    }
}
```

one more thing, check the location of your qml file, it should be accessible to the binary.

Comment: ok, you can try assigning an objectName property to the root object in Qml and instead of using rootObject, try finding the object via objectName

Comment: this mostly happens if application is unable to access Qml file from the given path

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use qobject_cast instead of dynamic_cast? See e.g. question 
[dynamic_cast returns NULL but it shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964746/dynamic-cast-returns-null-but-it-shouldnt)

Comment: Thanks for the info, but even after using qobject_cast, I don't get a valid pointer. I also tried to get a QGraphicsObject* from rootObject, but I still get a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`QGraphicsObject` is a `QObject` so no cast should be required. If your compiler complains, try adding `#include <QGraphicsObject>`.

Just casting without the compiler knowing the classes is asking for trouble. (Especially as there is multiple inheritance involved.)